# Where am I wrong on animate this background position?

Tags: jquery

Code :

```
$('#mappa-content').animate({ backgroundPosition: "0 -54px" }, 500);
```

the image in the background isn't moving. Why? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't animate `background-position` out of the box.

You can add support with [a plugin](http://www.protofunc.com/scripts/jquery/backgroundPosition/) (the site is down at the moment, so [here's a mirror](http://web.archive.org/web/20110514050638/http://www.protofunc.com/scripts/jquery/backgroundPosition/)).

You can animate `background-position-x` and `background-position-y`, but those properties aren't supported in for example Firefox/Opera.

Answer (score 1):

Quotations in selector:

```
$('#mappa-content').animate({ backgroundPosition: "0 -54px" }, 500);
```

Comment: @markzzz - No... I added a quotation mark at the end of the selector.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#mappa-content').animate({'background-position-x':'-54px'},500);
```

Comment: than you got problem with something else, show us your html and css.

Comment: ? No, image is not "moving", just height become more :O